# Error al usar URL para traer referencia de servicio

Tags: c#

Buenas obtengo el error de la imagen al querer importar el servicio WSAA en modo produccion. Estoy intentando con : https://wsaa.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms
Y obtengo este detalle de error.

```
Error al descargar 'https://wsaa.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms/$metadata'.
Error de solicitud con el siguiente estado HTTP 404: Not Found.
Los metadatos contienen una referencia que no se puede resolver: 'https://wsaa.afip.gov.ar/ws/services/LoginCms'.
El tipo de contenido text/xml;charset=utf-8 del mensaje de respuesta no coincide con el tipo de contenido del enlace (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). Si usa un codificador personalizado, asegúrese de que el método IsContentTypeSupported se implemente correctamente. Los primeros 561 bytes de la respuesta fueron: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
   <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
   <detail>
    <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">wsaa0.afip.gov.ar</ns2:hostname>
   </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'.
Error en el servidor remoto: (500) Error interno del servidor.
Si el servicio se define en la solución actual, intente compilar la solución y agregar de nuevo la referencia de servicio.
```

No se que puede ser o como resolverlo, ya probe hace 3 dias y daba el mismo error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las preguntas deben incluir tanto el código como el mensaje de error como texto, las imágenes son solo como apoyo, y la tuya está tan pixelada que ni para eso sirve.

Comment: Considerando que llevas casi 7 años en la plataforma, lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Listo ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: Según lo que dice el error y asumiendo que estaba funcionando, existe la posibilidad que `afip.gob.ar` haya cambiado la URL de ese servicio, también que le hayan dado de baja. ¿Hay algún lugar para revisar la documentación de ese servicio al que te intentas conectar?

Comment: https://www.afip.gob.ar/ws/documentacion/wsaa.asp en ese sitio están las URL al final y son las que estoy usando.